# In Jmeter how to extract a particular value from a response

Tags: jmeter

eg. I've received below response, so how to extract the value after akk in jmeter

eg : url":"https://gmail.com/user/v1/akk/48c68457-df8a-44e6-bca3-3874f87b3b35"

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

To extract [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) from your responce try this regexp:

```
akk\/((\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1})\"
```

You can test and learn regular expressions [here](https://regexr.com/) and [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Have tried Regular Expression Extractor but not able to extract the particular value after akk/

Comment: Your value looks like a UID, so you can use UID reg exp https://www.regextester.com/94410

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above response
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `akk`
   - Regular Expression: `/akk/(.+?)"`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image]
3. That should be it, now you should be able to access the extracted value as `${akk}` where required

   [image]

   Regular expression explanation:

   - `.` - match any character
   - `+` - one or more times
   - `?` - don't be greedy, i.e. stop when first match succeeds
   - `()`- grouping

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)?

Here, you'd set the left boundary as akk/ and the right boundary as "

That'd extract the content in between. I've used these before and they work quite nicely.